# Angular App points to localhost instead of remote server for data requests

Tags: node.js, angular, localhost, angular5, angular-routing

I'm trying to connect to a remote node.js server using http://server:3000.  When I query the server for data, I get no data back.  I look at the browser debugger and see that it's looking localhost:3000/page, and obviously getting no data.
  Part of app.module.ts

```
`   providers: [DateRangeService, CategoryserviceService,
  { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: getBaseUrl }]
   // providers: [DateRangeService]
  })
 export class AppModule { }

export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}`
```

The calling code looks like this
   
    `constructor(http: Http, private drs: DateRangeService, @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) 
    private baseurl: string) {
        this.demoId = "ex1";
        this.http = http;
      }
    ... 
    this.http.get(this.baseurl + volumeURL, {
         params: {
        //     // startdate: this.startdate.value,
        startdate: sdate,
        enddate: edate`

I end-up with an error http://localhost:3000/volumes?startdate=2018-6-20&enddate=2018-7-4 that the data can't be reached.  Or in other words, it's point to the localhost instead of the server that is serving the pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy setting for the service URLs

<kbd>proxy.cofig.json</kbd>

```
{
  "/rest": {
    "target": "http://server:3000/",
    "secure": false
  },
 "/other": {
    "target": "http://server:8060/",
    "secure": false
  }  
}
```

Then serve using `proxy-config`

```
 ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself well enough. The only thing running on the client side is the browser. The server is running node.js via npm start. I use chrome type in the server address and the app loads, except for the http calls fail because its looking at the client.